# Intellij Idea: Issues with building project using IBM JDK 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, gradle

I've a project which has requirement to use with IBM JDK 7. I'm using Intellij Idea 15.0.2 on windows 7. My project is multi-module maven project and uses some groovy scripts and also uses gradle to flatten the POMs using maven `org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin`. Now when I try to build my application (`Build -> Rebuild Project`), I get a one liner error in Messages window

> Error:java.lang.NullPointerException

When I check build.log (C:\Users\.IntelliJIdea15\system\log\build-log\build.log), I see following exception. As soon as I change the project SDK to Oracle JDK 7, everything works fine. Any idea on whats going wrong here?

[Update 1:] I also tried to invalidate cache and restarted idea, just to rule out cache is playing foul play here.

```
2015-12-22 14:16:23,343 [   4126]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.ProjectBuildException: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.GroovyBuilder.build(GroovyBuilder.java:142)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1230)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:904)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:976)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:870)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:695)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:386)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:193)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:294)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:273)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:731)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:707)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.createCompilationClassLoader(InProcessGroovyc.java:179)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovyc(InProcessGroovyc.java:76)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.GroovyBuilder.runGroovycOrContinuation(GroovyBuilder.java:201)
     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.GroovyBuilder.build(GroovyBuilder.java:117)
     ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that this is actually a bug with v15.0.2. Workaround is to add `-Didea.parallel.class.loader=false` under `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | User-local build process VM options`

[image]

More details [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149187). Fix should be available with v15.0.3. Till that time this workaround works (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea on whats going wrong here?

IF we look to [InProcessGroovyc.createCompilationClassLoader](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/b2f9ce2f8410efbfe171b88a7a74b1f07d90efb9/plugins/groovy/jps-plugin/src/org/jetbrains/jps/incremental/groovy/InProcessGroovyc.java), we can see code

```
 private JointCompilationClassLoader createCompilationClassLoader(Collection<String> compilationClassPath) throws Exception {
    ClassLoader parent = obtainParentLoader(compilationClassPath);

    ClassLoader groovyClassLoader = null;
    try {
      ClassLoader auxiliary = parent != null ? parent : buildCompilationClassLoader(compilationClassPath, null).get();
      Class<?> gcl = auxiliary.loadClass("groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader"); // 179 line, we throw NullPointer Exception
```

In ClassLoader.loadClass

```
public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return loadClass(name, false); // 131 line
}


protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
        throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
            // First, check if the class has already been loaded
            Class<?> c = findLoadedClass(name); // return null if class not found
```

So main problem that `IBM JDK 7` can't find `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader`, please check that groovy install correctly, `IBM JDK` can see groovy lib (groovy was downloaded, `GROOVY_HOME` environment variable is set correctly and `GROOVY_HOME/bin` added to your `PATH` environment variable).

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer. As I mentioned in my my question mine is maven based project, so I've groovy defined as maven dependency and not referring to groovy binaries locally `GROOVY_HOME/bin`. Am I misreading your answer here?

Comment: It's look like as IDEA can't see groovy when it was downloaded by maven, can you try download groovy manually and set all setting by hand? May be it's help you

Comment: I don't think that is the case, or else it should not work with Oracle JDK as well.

Comment: Not, every JDK has different algoritms how they find class and what it need to do, if it can't find. Why do you not just try download groovy manually and set all setting by hand?

Comment: For the sake of test, I did following

    1. I downloaded groovy binary
    2. Set GROOVY_HOME
    3. Set GROOVY_HOME\bin to PATH
    4. Restarted IDEA
    5. Tried to Rebuild the project. 

Result is still the same.